# Delphi XE6 - How to disable AQTime?

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, delphi-xe6, aqtime

I am working on tracking down some memory leaks... I enabled the free version of AQTime that comes with XE6 to do code profiling.  It runs and generates a report for me showing me my various memory leaks... I now want to DISABLE it.  I have set my build configuration to RELEASE and recompiled, but this did not help.

I have looked around in the AQ Menu (from within the Delphi IDE).  There is a Disable Profiling menu option, but it is grayed out... How do I get the option to turn OFF AQTime now...?

Comment: You want to disable it in your project, or remove it from your IDE?

Comment: Just from the project.

Comment: Have you just tried exiting the IDE? I don't have the AQTime IDE wizard loaded, because it keeps crashing my IDE.

Comment: Yes, didn't help any.  I have even tried loading a different project, and then going back to my original project

Comment: I recommend you actually unload the IDE package. It's found as an entry here in registry:  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\14.0\Known Packages`  Find the AQTime item and delete it.

Comment: @WarrenP - what is the name of the BPL?

Comment: Probably has AQ in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up uninstalling it.  Thanks...